# IBM Mobilefirst 6.3 application console - Dropdown next to application version is disabled

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I have developed an hybrid application. When I deployed this app on local server, I observed the dropdown next to the application version number is disabled. Can someone please help to locate the setting in the code which could disable this dropdown? Attaching screenshot for reference.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: This should not be. Are you observing this in a Studio or a Standalone server? What is the specific and complete version?

Comment: I am using Server version: 6.3.0.00.20150706-0811. I just observed that in application descriptor file, I have security test added to the application version - 

  <ipad bundleId="com.ibm.test" version="1.1" securityTest="FQRServicesAdapter-securityTest">
  <worklightSettings include="false"/>
  <security>
  <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
  <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false"  ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
  </security>
  </ipad>
If I remove security test then its getting enabled. But this should not happned right?

Comment: I take it this is a custom security test and you do not have wl_RemoteDisableRealm added to it?

Comment: Yes you are right this is custom security test. I am not aware of wl_RemoteDisableRealm. Is it something I need to add in application descriptor file? It will be great if you give me some inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

Custom security tests do not contain any realms under it. It is left to the developer to add the required set of realms.

In your scenario, to get remote disable option activated, you should modify your customSecurityTest in authenticationConfig.xml and add

```
<test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm"/>
```

to it.

For example, the following customSecurityTest :

```
<customSecurityTest name="customTests">
     <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="1"/>
     <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="1"/>
     <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

has antiXSRF, remoteDisable and DirectUpdate realms added and no more.

Note: If you are making a modification to authenticationConfig.xml, ensure you redeploy the modified runtime war file.

More details about pre-defined authentication realms [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding_predefined_worklight_authentication_realms_and_security_tests11?lang=en).